# No "hardware accelleration" enable/disable on internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, flash, flash-player

In chrome if I right click on a flash video and go on "settings" in the context menu I get a tab in which I can enable/disable video accelleration.

How come this tab is not present if I do the same on internet explorer?

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know chrome uses it's own Pepperflash plugin, not the Adobe Flash Player itself (at least on OSX). You can look this info up when you access this page:

```
chrome://flash
```

and also change certain advanced settings in:

```
chome://flags
```

I like the pepperflash pluin, because you don't need to install flash every time and it's beautifully sandboxed in chrome.

IE of course has to fall back to the Adobe Flash Player being installed on your System.